# How do I link to a settings page in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a WordPress plugin. I have a settings page created using `admin_menu` action.

In the function handler that's registered with `admin_menu`, I have some code to parse `$_GET` variable:

```
if ($_GET['action'] === "create") {
... // display form to save a new object
}
```

My question is, how can I create a link to link to this form?
Essentially, I want to link to my settings page and pass `action=create` as a query parameter.

**Update**
Here's more code that's relevant:

```
public static function zrdn_recipe_indexes()
{
    wp_enqueue_style("bootstrap-3", ZRDN_PLUGIN_URL . '/vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET')
    {
        switch($_GET['action'])
        {
            case "create":
            {
                self::create_index_page();
                break;
            }
            default: // list
            {
                $indexes = self::get_indexes();

                self::view('recipe_indexes/list', array(
                    "recipe_indexes" => $indexes
                ));
            }
        }
    }
}




public static function zrdn_menu_pages() {

    ...
    $recipe_indexes_page_title = "Recipe Indexes";
        $recipe_indexes_menu_title = $recipe_indexes_page_title;
        $recipe_indexes_menu_slug = "zrdn-recipe-indexes";
        $recipe_indexes_page_renderer = array('Recipes', 'zrdn_recipe_indexes');
        add_submenu_page(
            $menu_slug, // parent_slug
            $recipe_indexes_page_title, // page_title
            $recipe_indexes_menu_title, // menu_title
            $capability, // capability
            $recipe_indexes_menu_slug, // menu_slug
            $recipe_indexes_page_renderer // callback function
        );
}

add_action('admin_menu', array('MyClass', 'zrdn_menu_pages' ));
```

Comment: Can you please add your whole code?

Comment: @KaushaMehta, updated with more code. Trying to link to that `case "create":` part.

Comment: [add_query_arg](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/)

Comment: @davidcondrey, how do I get the last param: `$old_query_or_uri`?